# ViewPager for tutorial when app first starts only

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I would like to have 3 to 4 slides/pages to show a tutorial as of how the application works. This would only show up the first time the application starts after that, THE NEXT TIME the app is opened it will not show up again but go straight into the application.

I have the code to do the `ViewPager` already.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your app version code in your [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Whenever the app starts, check to see if the current version code is higher than the saved code. If it is, then you can show the ViewPager tutorial. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274315/3681880) for more.

**Other Links**

- [Determine if android app is the first time used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)
- [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)
- [Preload fragment's view in ViewPager on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341779/preload-fragments-view-in-viewpager-on-first-run)
- [android: How can I implement first time tutorial like Go Launcher in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805890/android-how-can-i-implement-first-time-tutorial-like-go-launcher-in-my-app)
- [How to implement first launch tutorial like Android Lollipop apps: Like Sheets, Slides app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954217/how-to-implement-first-launch-tutorial-like-android-lollipop-apps-like-sheets)
- [Android "first time" app user tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279144/android-first-time-app-user-tutorial)